List GPUs and related environment variables
I once came across a terminal command that lists the available GPUs on the system along with the environment variables for using them. For example, my laptop has an Nvidia dGPU and an Intel Arc iGPU, so I would get 2 results with the Nvidia card mentioning __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME / __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD / __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus and for the Intel card I would get DRI_PRIME.
My problem is that I cannot recall the command that provided this information. Does anyone know this utility?

Not exactly what you are looking for, but lsgpu from intel-gpu-tools and How to get the GPU info? might be helpful

No, that's not it. I wish I had made a note of that command... I think I saw it in a bug report of some Wayland issue in Gnome's gitlab, but for the life of me I can't recall what it was...

One or more of lshw, lsusbn̈ lspci?

any of this ?
vulkaninfo, glxinfo, prime-run

Finally found it again! It was "switcherooctl"...
Sample output:
❯ switcherooctl 
Device: 0
  Name:        Intel Corporation Meteor Lake-P [Intel Arc Graphics]
  Default:     yes
  Discrete:    no
  Environment: DRI_PRIME=pci-0000_00_02_0

Device: 1
  Name:        NVIDIA Corporation AD107M [GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile]
  Default:     no
  Discrete:    yes
  Environment: __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only

